# How to handle a race condition to renew session?

Tags: node.js, session

I've recently written a session management plugin in node.js for Muneem web framework. Here is pseudo code to create a new session;

```
function createSession(){
    // read encrypted session-id from the request
    if( sessionId ){
      // decrypt it
      if (decryptedSessionId ) {
        //read session detail from the store
        options.store.get(decryptedSessionId, (err, sessionFromStore) => {
          if(err){
            throw Error(err);
          }else if( sessionFromStore){
            if( shouldRenew(sessionFromStore) ){
              //delete previous session
              options.store.destroy(sessionFromStore.id, err=> {
                //update the session object in memory
              });
            }
          }else{ //session detail is not present in store
            // create new session
          }
        }); 
      } else { //invalid or tempered session
        // throw error
      }
    }else{ //session-id is not presnet in request
      // create new session
    }
}
```

As you can notice, I'm renewing a session when it is valid and satisfy certain conditions by deleting the previous session. But I don't update it in the store immediately. Instead, I update the session information in the store and set the cookies when the response is being sent to the client.

Now suppose a condition, when the server receives multiple requests with the same session-id which is eligible to renew. I renew the session on the first request.

*Scenarios*

1. Session is not updated in store. So I'll renew the previous session with another new session id. A user will have multiples session-id in this case.
2. Session is updated in the store. Now, the previous session will not be available in the store. I'll have to ask the user to login again if it is authorized session. Or I'll create another session.

How to handle this race condition?

[Here](https://github.com/node-muneem/satr) is the full code, in case we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation seems not to occur if we authenticate the main route only.

I was previously thinking to authenticate every request. A server can receive multiple requests with the same session ID only on page load which includes access to the main route along with static files like CSS, js, etc. Static files are not required to be authenticated. Hence race condition should not occur.